# Laravel nova Relationships

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to attach `ManyToMany` and create `HasOne`, `HasMany` relations while creating main item in laravel nova? I have no problem with `BelongsTo`, but others doesn't show up while creating new item

```
BelongsTo::make('Creator'),
BelongsToMany::make('Genre', 'genres'),
HasOne::make('GameImage', 'image'),
HasMany::make('GameScreen', 'screens'),
```

Comment: without code we can't check in detail what goes wrong. Add your relevant code.

Comment: Edited answer, but nothing is wrong with the code, I think it's not built in functionality

Answer (score 1):

By default Nova is set up to add some of the relations only when editing but Belongs To Many can be done with this package.

https://novapackages.com/packages/dillingham/nova-attach-many

In your resource file
`AttachMany::make('Objectives')->sortable()->hideFromIndex()`